# How To send array in params in fast android networking library

Tags: java, android, arrays, json

I am using Fast-Android-Networking and I want to send data to server which contains strings and arrays. It's ok to send string but I am unable to send array its not array list. It's simple array.
I have search other solution but all are regarding volley.
can anyone help? 
Please dont mark duplicate.
The last 5 parameters are arrays. I tried it as String.valueOf(ReadQuran) but it also didn't work.

**My Code:**

```
 AndroidNetworking.post(Api.ROOT_URL +"api/stageFiveFormData")
            .addBodyParameter("mto_id",idu)
            .addBodyParameter("school_id", scholid)
            .addBodyParameter("person_name", personnameS)
            .addBodyParameter("designation", designantionS)
            .addBodyParameter("cell_number",personcellS)
            .addBodyParameter("email",emailpersonS)
            .addBodyParameter("whatsapp_number",whatsApppersonS)
            .addBodyParameter("school_name",schoolNameS)
            .addBodyParameter("postal_address",postalAdressS)
            .addBodyParameter("city",cityS)
            .addBodyParameter("tehsil",tehsilS)
            .addBodyParameter("district",districtS)
            .addBodyParameter("s_primary", priamryChecked)
            .addBodyParameter("s_middle", middleChecked)
            .addBodyParameter("s_high", highChecked)
            .addBodyParameter("s_higher", hsChecked)
            .addBodyParameter("principal_name", nameOfPrincipalS)
            .addBodyParameter("p_contact_num",cellNoPrincipalS)
            .addBodyParameter("p_email",emailPrincipalS)
            .addBodyParameter("p_whatsapp_number",whatsAppPrincipalS)
            .addBodyParameter("class", Class)
            .addBodyParameter("rq_book", String.valueOf(ReadQuran))
            .addBodyParameter("rqb_qty", String.valueOf(ReadQuranQty))
            .addBodyParameter("fq_book", String.valueOf(FehamQuran))
            .addBodyParameter("fqb_qty", String.valueOf(FehamQuranQty))




            .setPriority(Priority.HIGH)
            .build()
            .getAsString(new StringRequestListener() {
                public void onResponse(String response) {
                    try {
                        JSONArray jsonArray = new JSONArray(response);
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonArray.getJSONObject(0);
                        String result = jsonObject.getString("result");
                        String message = jsonObject.getString("message");


                        if (result.equalsIgnoreCase("success")) {
                            Toast.makeText(FormStage5.this, "" + message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            Intent intent = new Intent(FormStage5.this, formstage2submittedmsg.class);
                            startActivity(intent);


                            pDialog.dismiss();
                        } else/* (result.equalsIgnoreCase("0"))*/ {
                            Toast.makeText(FormStage5.this, ""+message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            pDialog.dismiss();
                        }

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        pDialog.dismiss();
                        Toast.makeText(FormStage5.this, "Something Went Wrong , Try Again", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }

                }


                @Override
                public void onError(ANError anError) {
                    Toast.makeText(FormStage5.this, "Please Check Your Internet Connection" + anError.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    pDialog.hide();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to create a POJO class and set Array value, then pass it. It will automatically gets converted into JSON, if you are using retrofit with GSONConverter factory.

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answer to this question talks about Retrofit and GSON, while the question is about Fast Android Networking. The accepted answer did not work for me.

I found that the only way to do this was to build the body myself and add it to the request with `.addJSONObjectBody`.

I wanted a body that looks like:

```
{
    "roles": [
        "customer-admin"
    ]
}
```

The final way I found which works is:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

JSONObject roles;
try {
    roles = new JSONObject();
    JSONArray rolesArr = new JSONArray();
    rolesArr.put("customer-admin");
    roles.put("roles", rolesArr);
} catch (JSONException e) {
    // Make error toast here
    return;
}
            
AndroidNetworking.post(url)
    .addJSONObjectBody(roles)
    .build()
```

Comment: how about JSONArray ?

{
    "roles": "customer-admin",
    "id": "1"
}

Answer (score 0):

pass the arrayname.toString() as a value